# How to install Java 8 on Alpine Linux?

Tags: java, alpine-linux

When I look at package lists they suggest that all sorts of Java 8 packages exist for Alpine, but when I try to install them I always get:

```
apk add openjdk8
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  openjdk8-jre (missing):
    required by: world[openjdk8]
```

And this also happens with other Java 8 packages, such as openjdk8-jre.

According to this:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openjdk8&branch=v3.10&arch=x86_64
the package exists for version 3.10 64 bit, which I'm using, so why wouldn't it install?

Comment: Could you post the contents of `/etc/apk/repositories`?

Comment: @valiano After looking at that file, I noticed that most repos were commented out, after uncommenting them "openjdk8" installed, thanks

Answer (score 9):

openjdk is in the community repo.
It seems that you didn't enable community repo.
Go ahead and first enable community repo by uncommenting the community repo in `/etc/apk/repositories`, then run `apk update` then execute `apk add openjdk11`.

Comment: Seems to be what [solved the OP's problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556962/how-to-install-java-8-on-alpine-linux/577486#comment1034884_556962)

Answer (score 4):

Try another version of [openJdk8](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.10/community/x86_64/openjdk8):

RUN apk add openjdk8=8.242.08-r0